# How to convert a Javascript number to a Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bit-manipulation, arraybuffer, uint8array

I have a Javascript integer (whose precision can go up to `2^53 - 1`), and I am trying to send it over the wire using an `ArrayBuffer`. I suppose I could use `BigInt64Array`, but the browser support still seems relatively new with that.

I cannot use `Int32Array` (which was my original solution), because the precision for that is up to `2^32 - 1`, whereas a Javascript integer can safely go up to `2^53 - 1`. This is my problem.

Is there an easy way to simply turn any Javascript integer into a `Uint8Array` of length 8?

For example, I am looking for a function like this:

```
function numToUint8Array(num) {
  let arr = new Uint8Array(8);

  // fill arr values with that of num

  return arr;
}

let foo = numToUint8Array(9458239048);
let bar = uint8ArrayToNum(foo); // 9458239048
```

Does something like this exist in the standard library already? If not, is there a way to write something like this?

Comment: "*Does something like this exist in the standard library already?*" - the `BigInt64Array` you already mentioned. "*Is there a way to write something like this?*" - just repeatedly divide by 256 and write `num % 256` as one byte into your `Uint8Array`. Make sure to decide on the endianness.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, okay. And what is the formula for converting it back? `uint8ArrayToNum` I'm trying to think through it but not sure if I have it right. Going to post an answer.

Comment: What are the elements of `foo` expected to be for your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Bergi, is something like this what you had in mind?

```js
function numToUint8Array(num) {
  let arr = new Uint8Array(8);

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    arr[i] = num % 256;
    num = Math.floor(num / 256);
  }

  return arr;
}

function uint8ArrayToNumV1(arr) {
  let num = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    num += Math.pow(256, i) * arr[i];
  }

  return num;
}

function uint8ArrayToNumV2(arr) {
  let num = 0;

  for (let i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    num = num * 256 + arr[i];
  }

  return num;
}

let foo = numToUint8Array(9458239048);
let bar = uint8ArrayToNumV1(foo); // 9458239048
let baz = uint8ArrayToNumV2(foo); // 9458239048

console.log(foo, bar, baz);
```

Comment: Yes, basically that, although I'd have used `num = num *  256 + arr[i]` (and reverse iteration) in `uint8ArrayToNum`, for better symmetry with `numToUint8Array`.

Comment: Cool. that's even better. Editing my answer to include that one as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Math class, you can use this script:

```
function numToUint8Array(num) {
  const arr = new Uint8Array(8);
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    arr.set([num/0x100**i], 7-i)

  return arr;
}

function uint8ArrayToNum(arr) {
   let num = 0;
   
   for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      num += (0x100**i) * arr[7-i];
   return num;
}
```

Test Code:

```
  const arr = numToUint8Array(257);
  console.log(arr);
  const num = uint8ArrayToNum(arr);
  console.log(num);
```

Result:

```
Uint8Array(8) [
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 1
]
257
```